# MYSQL sum() with exclusion of records

Tags: mysql, sum, case

I need to calculat fin_sum for visit_numbers and industry_code, but if id in other table then i need to exclude records which have id in other table from calculation but, if id is not esixst in table themn it should be included.

I have table with next structure

```
create temporary table client_transactions_final
    (
    id int,
    fin_amount decimal (6,2),
    ind_code varchar(10),
    visit_number int 
    );

insert into client_transactions_final values 
    (1, 100, 'Ind 1', 2),
    (1, 300, 'Ind 2', 3),
    (2, 300, 'Ind 3', 4),
    (2, 100, 'Ind 1', 2),
    (3, 300, 'Ind 2', 3),
    (4, 300, 'Ind 3', 5),
    (5, 100, 'Ind 1', 2),
    (6, 300, 'Ind 2', 5),
    (6, 300, 'Ind 3', 4)


create temporary table term_map
(
id int
);  

insert into term_map values 
    (2),
    (4);
```

from this table i am runing select which do sum groyp by visit_numbers and industry code

```
SELECT visit_number, 

        case when id in (SELECT id FROM term_map) then 
        --sum(fin_amount) do not include ids from SELECT id FROM term_map into 
        else 
        SUM(fin_amount) end revenue
    FROM
        client_transactions_final
    GROUP BY visit_number , ind_code
```

Howewer i need to calculat fin_sum for visit_numbers and industry_code, but if id in other table then i need to exclude records which have id in other table from calculation but, if id is not esixst in table themn it should be included. I alreade try difrentaproaches on how to do it but non of it is  working any ideas how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT visit_number, 
        SUM(fin_amount) revenue
    FROM
        client_transactions_final
        where id not in (SELECT id FROM term_map)
    GROUP BY visit_number , ind_code
```

Comment: it will work only, for those cases when id not in select. but if id in select ? it also have to be calculaded but client_transactions_final should not include ids from SELECT id FROM term_map

Comment: @Andrey you said in your question that if id is in the other table (term_map) then the amounts should not be included in the sum, which is what this does. If that is not the case, can you provide your expected output data for this query?

Comment: This query is as per your requirement as i understood by your question if not so then provide what output you expect from this data that will help to understand the problem